# I can't find apache/htdocs on my Mac OS and could anyone explain the following sentences' meaning?

Tags: php, apache, variable-assignment

Our teacher gives us  a sample CodeIgniter application which is named "timetable.tar" Then he asks for running this application through following steps:

1. Uncompress and untar the file
2. Install it under apache/htdocs
3. Change the values of the database, username, and password settings in    airuoft/application/config/database.php to the appropriate values for your database.
   Start Apache
4. ....

I am really confused with the step 2. and i can't find apache/htdocs folder on my Mac OS X 10.8.4

BTW, I have already installed PHP and Apache.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you have installed apache and php, if it doesnt you can dowloand

http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

It's easy to use and install you can find in:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs
```

http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/first-steps

Comment: If you're on MAMP then your public folder must be here `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`

Comment: you have to install first, download it from http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html and after install you can find in application/mamp/httdocs/...this is for mac

Answer (score 2):

By default, on Mac OS, it's located at

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents
```